# start common node in erlang shell

Tags: erlang

Facing problem with slave:start/2 in lion OS, so I have to try another direction "start common node with os:cmd automatically" in erlang shell.

One way is by command directly, and another way is through bash file. But both way faces the same problem. If can't start automatically, I have to start node manually everytime.

```
Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)1> os:cmd("erl -name abcd").
"Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)\n(abcd@yus-iMac.local)1> *** Terminating erlang ('abcd@yus-iMac.local')\n"
(emacs@yus-iMac.local)3> os:cmd("~/Documents/Project/node_start").
"Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)\n(abc@yus-iMac.local)1> *** Terminating erlang ('abc@yus-iMac.local')\n"
```

The bash file content is as follows:

```
#/bin/sh
erl -name abc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I'm really fond of this approach, but to make the above work you should pass the "detached" parameter to the 'erl' command:

```
erl -name foo

1> os:cmd("erl -name bar -detached").
[]

2> net_adm:ping('bar@pigeon.local').
pong

3> nodes().
['bar@pigeon.local']
```

Reading from the [doc](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html):

> -detached
>
> Starts the Erlang runtime system detached from the system console. Useful for running daemons and backgrounds processes. Implies
>   -noinput.